# Failed to instantiate module, AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

Im trying to use angular-file-upload, https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload.

When I try to Instantiate the module, angularFileModule, I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module cryptlib due to: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularFileUpload due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularFileUpload' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I'm trying to Instantiate it in my app.js file:

```
var gameApp = angular.module("cryptlib", [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'cryptlib_controllers',
    'cryptlib_directives',
    'cryptlib_services',
    'angularFileUpload'
]);

angular.module('cryptlib_controllers', []);
angular.module('cryptlib_directives', []);
angular.module('cryptlib_services', []);

gameApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/firstpage.html',
            controller  : 'firstPageController'
    })

    .when('/game', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/uploadBook.html',
            controller  : 'uploadBookController'
    });

});
```

I have no Idea why this wont work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you included the js file for angular-file-upload, and is it included _before_ your apps js file(s)?

Comment: move the 'angularFileUpload' initialization in next of 'ngSanitaize' ..then try

Comment: @Asik: What do you mean?

Jiml: Thank you, it worked :-). My bad.

Comment: Change the order.. angular.module("cryptlib", [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize','angularFileUpload',
    'cryptlib_controllers',
    'cryptlib_directives',
    'cryptlib_services'
]);

Comment: @Asik: That was not the problem. The problem was that I didn't include it before my apps.